# join kusto database with a function from another database

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

**Edit:**

Below are more details about what I am trying to achieve.

I have 1 cluster with two databases. Database1 contains Table1 with the below info

[image]

[image]

DB2 contains a table with the below info:
[image]

UniqueID contains the same data as userID on table1.

In DB2, I have a function that performs some filtering on Unique ID.

[image]

[image]

I know that I can join both tables as the below screenshot, but my production example is way more complex than that and requires me to use the function.

[image]

My goal is to run the Table1 query, and pass the the userID to the function getuserproperties, to get a merged output.

Something Like this which does not work :)

[image]

Comment: Those are obscure and contradictions requirements. Please share data sample (preferably as a datatable) + required results, in table format.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to make some dummy data to demonstrate tomorrow.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I have updated with some example and pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it :) It was very simple :)

```
let UID = 7;
database('db1').Table1
| join kind=leftouter database('db2').Table2 on $left.userID==$right.UniqueID
| where userID == toscalar(getUserProperties(UID))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to make much sense... You already have userID/UniqueID (as UID) so what's the use of getUserProperties?

Comment: yes true. because initially I was trying to pass the results from the first query to the function to get all the results merged not only a specific UID. similar to what join can do. getUserProperties is just for demonestration, but in the actual production it is a very complex function that gets results from multiple clusters and DBs. and what am trying to do is to list the users in table1 and pipe the results to that function. but this does not seem to be possible unless I manually specified the userid.